# Let $f:A→B$ be an onto function and let $T⊆B$. Prove that $(f◦f^{-1})(T) =T$

Tags: real-analysis, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Let $f:A→B$ be an onto function and let $T⊆B$.  Prove that $(f◦f^{−1})(T) = T$

How would I go about proving this?

> Let $x$ be an element of $(f◦f^{−1})(T)$.
>
> By the definition of composition/composite functions, $\text{Dom}(f◦f^{−1}) = \text{Dom}(f)$ and the $\text{Ran}(f◦f^{−1}) = \text{Ran}(f^{-1})$.
>
> By the definition of the inverse, the range of $f^{-1}$ is the domain of $f$.
>
> Thus $(f◦f^{−1})(T)$ is a function from $A$ to $A$. (?)

I can't get much past this. My prof hinted to using double containment but I can't get past the first part.

Comment: If $f$ is merely onto, then I don't think there's any guarantee that $f^{-1}$ exists. Are you sure that your prof doesn't mean for $f^{-1}(T)$ to be interpreted as the preimage of $T$ under $f$, i.e. the set $\{a \in A : f(a) \in T\}$? If so, then I would guess that $(f \circ f^{-1})(T)$ should be interpreted as $\{y \in B : \exists a \in f^{-1}(T)  \text{ s.t. } y = f(a)\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An important point here is that $f^{-1}(z)$ must be treated as a *set*, whereas $f(w)$ is a single *element*.

Note that

$(f \circ f^{-1})(T) = f(f^{-1}(T)). \tag 0$

Let

$z \in (f \circ f^{-1})(T)  = f(f^{-1}(T)); \tag 1$

then in accord with (0) there is some

$w \in   f^{-1}(T) \subset A \tag 2$

with

$z = f(w); \tag 3$

but (2) implies

$f(w) \in T; \tag 4$

thus,

$z \in T, \tag 5$

and

$f(f^{-1}(T)) \subset T; \tag{5.5}$

to go the other way, observe that

$z \in T \tag 6$

with

$w \in f^{-1}(z) \subset f^{-1}(T) \tag 7$

yields

$z = f(w) \in f(f^{-1}(T)) \subset T; \tag 8$

this shows

$T \subset f(f^{-1}(T)); \tag 9$

(5.5) and (9) together imply

$T = f(f^{-1}(T)), \tag{10}$

the requisite result.